# saving embedded documents mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a person model which `embeds_many` addresses.

Is there a way to always clear embedded relationship when updating?
For example, If I send a complete representation of a person, including addresses, I want to replace existing addresses rather than appending them.

My temp fix is a `before_save` callback which clear out all addresses

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :addresses

  before_save :clear_addresses!

  def clear_addresses!
    self.unset(:addresses)
  end
end
```

Comment: If you do that, why having a embeds_many addresses ? because you never have this addresses associate to your person ....

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an empty `addresses` params when you update your person

```
person.update_attributes(:addresses => [])
```

Comment: Yes, I sure can. But what I want to do is to _clear every time_. If addresses is passed these should override already persisted addresses.

Comment: I really don't understand the purpose :(

Comment: With my current setup addresses should be cleared unless it is sent to the server. So, not passing any addresses should clear out existing ones.